# How can I prevent OAuth server from remembering user?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I have a webapp which asks user several questions and store answers. User logs in via OAuth using external provider, then I get user ID information from external SSO server.

I need my app to be used by several users at the same computer, so every time the form is submitted, I need to log out the user. I can do it easily in my app, but then I redirect user to OAuth server again. OAuth server remembers user, so it gives the code of previously logged user right away. I want users to log in again at OAuth server though, but how can I do it? Is it possible to ask OAuth server not to remember the user that had logged in previously?

Answer (score 0):

From your question the actual flow is a bit unclear, however, there are two options:

- The client needs to log out after initial log in. With this, a new session flow will be initiated in the next iteration, forcing the client to have to log in again.
- The server needs to not remember consent ("Do you want to allow x on app y."), to ask the client for consent again.

Please be aware of the terms authentication, authorisation and consent have very specific meanings in this context.

You may want to share more details on the situation you are in, e.g. relevant code, the OAuth2 server you want to authorise with, including software, version and possibly url. Also, the client (as in [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1)) is of importance here, did you implement the oauth flow yourself or did you rely on any library? If yes, which?